# Template hierarchy: how to let category.php conditionally-load archive.php?

Tags: categories, template-hierarchy

In Wordpress template chaining for categories, we have WP looking for:

```
category-slug.php → category-id.php → category.php → archive.php → index.php
```

Now, I'd like to make some tweaks in category.php, for instance insert some conditions over there, and if the condition is true, use a particular template (custom) otherwise continue processing the chain moving control as usual to archive.php

How can I achieve that? I guess I will have to create a category.php file in my child-theme folder, insert conditional statements, and? How shall I instruct WP to continue to process the template chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, answer is linked below, and it turns out [Template Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) do the trick!

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252459/110886